# how to undo sp_addlinkedserver abc,'SQL Server'?

Tags: sql-server, database

Wow i was just playing around with sp_addlinkedserver and i accidentally ran this command: `sp_addlinkedserver abc,'SQL Server'`

1) i had command(s) completed successfully.. but what happened?

2) how do i undo what i did?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You created a link to a server named `abc`.

You could try to query the server across this link using a command such as:

```
select * 
from abc.master.information_schema.tables
```

But (unless you really do have a server called `abc`) it'll return you a message similar to:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "abc" returned message
>   "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online.".

You can view your linked server in SSMS under Server `Objects>>Linked Servers` in the Object Explorer.

To get rid of the linked server, use the following statement:

```
sp_dropserver abc
```

Comment: is there anyway to set up multiple "fake" servers within 1 computer for development?

Comment: Yes, use the SQL Server Configuration Manger to setup aliases to your own server. You can then setup links to these aliases. I used this recently to replicate an on-site configuration on a single server for testing.

Answer (score 10):

You now have a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) called `abc`

To remove, use [sp_dropserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174310.aspx) (There is no sp_droplinkedserver). Thus:

```
EXEC sp_dropserver 'abc', 'droplogins'
```

Comment: @Pacerier: for a single stored proc call, yes

Comment: heys i don't understand what you mean. what's a non-single stored proc call?

Comment: @Pacerier: If you have 2 stored procedure calls in the same batch, you need EXEC on the 2nd one eg EXEC proc1 .. EXEC proc2 .. GO

Comment: way cool, i'd always thought tbat we had to have an exec in its own batch to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You added the Linked Server, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) about using it. Briefly, Linked servers used to obtain the ability to make distributed queries between your and linked servers:

```
SELECT MyServer.MyDatabase.dbo.Table1.Field1, 
       LinkedServer.MyDatabase.dbo.Table2.Field2
FROM MyServer.MyDatabase.dbo.Table1 
INNER JOIN LinkedServer.MyDatabase.dbo.Table2 
   ON MyServer.MyDatabase.dbo.Table1.ID=LinkedServer.MyDatabase.dbo.Table2.ID
```

Comment: is there anyway to set up multiple "fake" servers within 1 computer for development?

Comment: I cannot see why not. try it, it's really interesting.